# Insufficient access rights

Tags: sql-server-express, sql-server-2019

Getting the following when trying to open a database in SQL Server Management Studio:

> Property TargetRecoveryTime is not available for Database '[AH_12]'.
> This property may not exist for this object, or may not be retrievable
> due to insufficient access rights. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

How can I get the database to accessible without admin rights.

Also how can you install SQL Server Express 2019 with user access rights rather than admin.

My install string has the following command:

```
setup.exe /Q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ACTION=install 
/FEATURES=SQLENGINE,SDK /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /SECURITYMODE=SQL 
/ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=true /INSTANCENAME=SPORTYENGINE19 /SAPWD="Sporty~asd
```

Thank you

Comment: You can't run the installer without admin rights. You can, however, install LocalDB -- that still requires admin rights, but afterwards any user can create locally accessible database instances.

Comment: The native database is legacy and needs to be expanded to multi user/instance, which as I understand you cannot do with localDB